# Compare number of files in one folder to check if there is some new

Tags: bash, file, logging, directory, compare

I have to check if in a specific folder there is some new file and, only if any, send me a notification.
I cannot install anything, so I have to use only Terminal and default preinstalled.
I think I can use this

```
ls -1A >/path/to/folder | wc -l
```

so that I can count number of file, but how can I log and compare previous count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run in a while loop and check for change after certain seconds repeatedly

```
num=`ls -la /path | wc -l`
while [ 1 ]
do
files=`ls -la /path | wc -l`
if [ $files -ne $num ]
then echo changed
num=$files
fi
sleep 5
done
```

Put it in a script.

Comment: [Why **not** parse `ls`?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: It says me `line 6: syntax error near unexpected token 'then'` what I'm wrong?

Comment: I mistyped `If` it should be `if`. Fixed now

Comment: Works perfectly! Only one last thing: now it says of course "changed" when a new file is added; but it continues to say that; is it possible to to that only one time and then, again, only if - for example n+1 - files are added?

Comment: Yes. Need to assign files to num. Check now

Comment: @Tarique may I ask you another thing? If I need to check at the same time more folder (every with different notification, for example 4) and not only one how can I do without run separately n different scripts?

Comment: @DylanDog can you use python? It's much easier to do your new request in python than bash. Otherwise to do this in bash, need to save the file count in each of those directories and then read and compare.

Comment: May you give me a simple example how to do this?

Comment: In case file number changed, `echo $num > .file_count` inside each of the directories. also touch this file at the start of script so that script doesn't count this file as a change. And in each iteration, read the file count from this file.